# Build Xcode project from Philips Hue EDK using cmake

Tags: xcode, cmake, philips-hue

I have downloaded an SDK from GitHub here: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/EDK that I want access to using Xcode. The README for this repo give these instructions to do this:

```
cd root-of-repo
mkdir build
cd build
cmake  ..
cmake --build .
```

Everything seems to download ok but I do not know how to add it to an Xcode project so I can start using the SDK. This is the first time I have tried to use cmake so I'm sure I have missed some steps. I'm just reaching out to see if anyone can help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Xcode` generator:

```sh
cd root-of-repo
cmake -S. -Bbuild -G "Xcode"
```

ref:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Xcode.html